# Formal "Thank you for your business" in german

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, formality

When invoicing clients, a lot of people add

> Thank you for your business!

at the end of the document.

The [linguee.de](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=Thank%20you%20for%20your%20business) does not provide us with suggestions unfortunately.

I would just translate it literally as

> Vielen dank für das Geschäft!

But nevertheless... are there better translations for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use "Vielen Dank für Ihren Einkauf (when selling something) / Ihren Besuch (in places with a cover charge) / Ihren Auftrag (when charging for a service)".

Comment: Ja, Sie haben recht! Habe es auf http://www.dict.cc/?s=Vielen+Dank+f%C3%BCr+Ihren+Auftrag auch gefunden. Vielen dank!